# Restoring XP using Linux Live with fdisk tool

Tags: linux, windows-xp, partitioning, restore

I am trying to create a restore  a windows operating system using Linux Live.

I have formatted the hard drive using FAT 32 format (mkfs.vfat) command.

I have created the partitions using the fdisk command. I formatted the individual partitions and copied the OS files into the disk.

I have re-written the mbr using ms-sys command. I have also set the active flag on the disk which is supposed to boot.

The operating system that I am trying to restore is Windows XP. I realized that the partition's LBA address is 2048. I changed it to 63 (since XP traditionally starts at 63).

The error that I get is "Missing operating system". I think linux is messing up the CHS data and that is the reason that I am not able to restore the OS. How do I correct this setting?

Comment: Boot from a XP disc, load recovery console then run the fixmbr command.

Comment: @Moab I could do that if all the machines are going to be under my control. I need to find a way so that the machines are shipped with a recovery disc. The MBR needs to be re-written by Linux

Comment: If all the systems have the same hardware, why not just do the initial build, then image using clonezilla or the like and ship with burned disk images?